# Using my own corpus for category classification in Python NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, machine-learning, nltk, corpus

I'm a NTLK/Python beginner and managed to load my own corpus using CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader but how do I actually train and use the data for classification of text?

```
>>> from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
>>> reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('/ebs/category', r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(.*)\.txt')
>>> len(reader.categories())
234
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275614/using-my-own-corpus-instead-of-movie-reviews-corpus-for-classification-in-nltk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want a naive Bayes classifier with bag of words features:

```
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.classify.naivebayes import NaiveBayesClassifier

def make_training_data(rdr):
    for c in rdr.categories():
        for f in rdr.fileids(c):
            yield FreqDist(rdr.words(fileids=[f])), c

clf = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(list(make_training_data(reader)))
```

The resulting `clf`'s `classify` method can be used on any `FreqDist` of words.

(But note: from your `cap_pattern`, it seems you have sample *and* a single category per file in your corpus. Please check whether that's really what you want.)