# nltk adding genre to files in corpus

Tags: nltk

I have a bunch of plain text files I want to classify into either class A or class B.

for training, I was thinking of adding the genre as class A or class B to each file and try to identify some features that are predictive of the genre of a file.
I can create a plain text corpus but is there any way to add the genre of a file while creating the corpus?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using my own corpus for category classification in Python NLTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818265/using-my-own-corpus-for-category-classification-in-python-nltk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest NLTK's [CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.api.CategorizedCorpusReader-class.html). The text files have to be named according to their category / genre and you have to pass a regular expression to the constructor that tells NLTK which file belongs to which category.

The documentation states:

> A regular expression pattern used to find the category for each file identifier. The pattern will be applied to each file identifier, and the first matching group will be used as the category label for that file.

Instead of a pattern, you can also pass a dictionary or a text file containing a mapping of fileids to category names. Please note that each text file can belong to multiple categories.

See [this blog entry](http://www.packtpub.com/article/python-text-processing-nltk-20-creating-custom-corpora) for code examples.