# how to create and label feature set in nltk

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

i want to do a sentiment analysis on twitter tweet and for that i have test data set in csv file in which tweet column as input but how to create a training data and how to label the data and how to use as feature set.

please correct me if I'm wrong here.. i have to manually create the feature set and label each word?

till now i have done word tokenize and stop word and porter stemming to my test dataset. now from here i want apply my training set and as output i want positive and negative tweet result. please give me some correct direction..

Comment: [Learning to Classify Text.](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107075/classification-using-movie-review-corpus-in-nltk-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275614/using-my-own-corpus-instead-of-movie-reviews-corpus-for-classification-in-nltk

Comment: @alvas thank you for the links.. it's really help me.

Comment: now i have another problem i.e. i don't have any labelled data. i want to train my test data against labelled train dataset. so, how i can make a labelled train dataset (label data should consist of negative and positive sentence/ words)?